# update one line with the average of other line

Tags: mysql, sql

I actually have a table like this : 
[image]
But I want to update the value of the first line to give it the value of the average of their child like this : 
[image]
So I've used this query :

```
UPDATE mytable parent
INNER JOIN mytable child
ON child.parentId = parent.id
SET parent.value = AVG(child.value)
WHERE parent.parentId=0
```

But I get this error : #1111 - Invalid use of group function 
How can I correct my query ?

Comment: Just a sidenote: Can there be more levels? Then handling this table can get quite complicated - especially in MySQL with the lack of recursive queries. If it is always just the two levels, however, then I'd probably simply use two tables, one for the parents, one for the children. And I wouldn't usually store data redundantly, which is what you are trying to do right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery to join on where you calculate the average for the parent id's

The query to get the average per parentId looks like:

```
SELECT parentId, AVG(value) as average FROM mytable GROUP BY parentId
```

So now join on it

```
UPDATE mytable parent
INNER JOIN (SELECT parentId, AVG(value) as average FROM mytable GROUP BY parentId) child
ON child.parentId = parent.id
SET parent.value = child.average
WHERE parent.parentId=0
```

Comment: You misplace your parenthesis. Can you correct you code please?  Then I'll validate your answer.

Answer (score 2):

For single record update you could use variable:

```
SET @id = 0;--your ID
SET @avgVal = SELECT AVG(value) FROM mytable WHERE parentId = @id;

UPDATE mytable parent
   SET parent.value = @avgVal
WHERE parent.parentId = @id;
```

Comment: I got this error : #1093 - You can't specify target table 'parent' for update in FROM clause